# R: Quarter Format to "year-month-day"

Tags: r, date, transform

my dataframe contains the following format of quarterly data in the first column

```
"1991 1.Q" 
"1991 2.Q" 
"1991 3.Q" 
"1991 4.Q" 
"1992 1.Q" 
"1992 2.Q"
```

I want to transform them, into

```
1991-01-01
1991-04-01
1991-07-01
1991-10-01
1992-01-01
```

Unfortunately I've no idea how to deal with it. I tried several methods with as.Date but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `as.yearqtr`

```
library(zoo)
df1[[1]] <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(df1[[1]], "%Y %q.Q"))
df1[[1]]
#[1] "1991-01-01" "1991-04-01" "1991-07-01" "1991-10-01" "1992-01-01" "1992-04-01"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("1991 1.Q", "1991 2.Q", "1991 3.Q", "1991 4.Q", 
"1992 1.Q", "1992 2.Q")), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```